# how to use php integer variable in javascript as integer variable

Tags: javascript, php

I have passed my php integer variable `$number` into javascript. 
But can't access that php variable without using quotation

```
<script>
 var number = '<?php echo $number?>';
</script>
```

if I use quotation it can accessible but don't get the integer value actually. It became string since use quotation.
Without quotation can't get anything.

I have googling that but don't get the appropriate answer yet.

How to get the integer value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For int simple remove the single quotes

```
<script>
     var number = <?php echo $number ?>;
</script>
```

Note : Make sure that $number should not empty . if it's empty use ternary operator if statement to handle that .  `var number =<?php echo !empty($number)? $number:0 ?>;`

Comment: it's not working @JYoThi. I user that at first without quotation. and try to show it ... but nothing showed

Comment: Just now i tested this in my localhost it's working `<script>
 
  var number =<?php echo $number=1 ?>
  
  alert(number);
 
</script>` @ArafatRahman

Answer (score 3):

Use parseInt function to convert it to integer

```
var number = parseInt('<?php echo $number; ?>');
```